# LIKE with Multiple Consecutive White Spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following query with `LIKE` predicate in SQL Server 2012. It replaces white spaces with %.  I have two records in the table.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (ITMEID INT, ITMDESC VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (1,'Healty and Alive     r')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (2, 'A liver patient')

DECLARE @SearchCriteria VARCHAR(100)
SET @SearchCriteria = 'Alive'

SELECT *
FROM @MyTable
WHERE (ITMDESC LIKE '%'+REPLACE(@SearchCriteria,' ','%')+'%' ESCAPE '\')
```

I got this query from a friend `to consider multiple consequent white spaces as a single space`. The challenge is I don't see any reference for this.

Is there a pitfall in the approach?

Comment: There's no occurrence of `alive` in the second entry - there's one for `a live` (with a **SPACE** in between!) but that's not the same! Otherwise, you'd have to search for `%a%live%`

Comment: @marc_s Okay.. I got this query from a friend to consider multiple consequent white spaces as a single space. The challenge is I don't see any reference for this? Do we have any reference for this approach in stack overflow?

Comment: @marc_s Agreed. That was my mistake. But do we have any references for this approach?

Answer (score 0):

`REPLACE(@SearchCriteria,' ','%')` always returns `Alive`. There is no `Alive` word in the second row, therefore it's not returned.

In fact, `WHERE` clause will look like this: `WHERE (ITMDESC LIKE '%Alive%' ESCAPE '\')`
The second row doesn't meet it.

Probably, you want something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM @MyTable
WHERE (REPLACE(ITMDESC,' ','') LIKE '%'+@SearchCriteria+'%' ESCAPE '\')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use as below

```
   DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (ITMEID INT, ITMDESC VARCHAR(100))

    INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (1,'Healty and Alive     r')
    INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (2, 'A liver patient')

    ECLARE @SearchCriteria VARCHAR(100)
    SET @SearchCriteria = 'Alive'

    SELECT *
    FROM @MyTable
   WHERE (REPLACE(ITMDESC,' ','') LIKE '%'+@SearchCriteria+'%' ESCAPE '\')
```

it will return both records as you want

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to replace all spaces with some moniker and then replace that moniker with a single space.

```
Select Replace(Replace(ItmDesc, ' ', '<z>'), '<z>', ' ')
From MyTable
```

[SQL Fiddle version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8638c/1)